# Difference between could and would

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, spoken-english

What is the difference between above two sentences?

1. Would you let me know, why did you go there?
2. Could you let me know, why did you go there?

I guess **would** is kind of  expecting a ***yes*** or ***no*** answer, whereas  **could** is asking for an explanation as an answer.

Am I right with my guess?

Answer (score -1):

There's essentially no difference between the sentences. In this case, "would" and "could" aren't asking for different information; they're both used to make the request "Let me know why you went there." more polite.